# Execute code before AWS LambdaEntryPoint / APIGatewayProxyFunction terminates

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an ASP .NET Core Web API app deployed to AWS through a serverless app, and I'm using the standard LambdaEntryPoint that looks like this:

```
public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Here I do my initialization, ok...
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected and request to API methods cause the lambdas to execute, but I don't see a way to execute code just before the lambda terminates...

I tried implementing `IDisposable` to my `LambdaEntryPoint`, but it's not getting called.

Is there a way to execute cleanup code before a lambda function terminates?

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are looking for is a place to run a piece of code right before the underlying Lambda compute container is reclaimed. In that case this is not possible. Lambda compute containers are frozen when there are no incoming request to process. If no request comes in after a certain point the Lambda compute container is reclaimed by the Lambda service and the code in the Lambda function is never aware when this happens.

Comment: Thank you @Norm Johanson, that's interesting. I'm confused how I'm supposed to handle the execution of tasks that are happening in a background thread... When a request is made, I start an operation on another thread and return a value to the caller. The other thread could take several seconds to complete... I need to tell AWS not to pause my lambda until my function finished executing... Is there something like that available?

Comment: Background tasks/thread in Lambda will yield unpredictable results due to the Lambda compute container's lifecycle. If you have more work you need to do but want to return a response back before that work is complete I would suggest putting that logic in a separate Lambda function. Then have the main function invoke the second function async to do the background processing and then return.